# Save specific words/numbers from PDF to Google Spreadsheet. (Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to read **special data from a PDF** and **insert** it into a **spreadsheet**.

*On the picture you can see what it should look like.*

I googled a lot but couldn't find the right one. Maybe someone can help me? Good Friday, cheers.

[image]

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const STOCKDATA_ROW_OFFSET = 5

function postpones() {
var cell = ss.getRange("A6").isBlank();
if (!cell){
ss.getRange(6, 1, ss.getLastRow() - STOCKDATA_ROW_OFFSET, ss.getLastColumn()).moveTo(ss.getRange(7, 1));}}
```

**UPDATE**:
I heard a lot. I can convert the PDF into a DOC. Unfortunately I'm not getting any further right now. The following is displayed.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const STOCKDATA_ROW_OFFSET = 5


function postpones() {
var cell = ss.getRange("A6").isBlank();
if (!cell){
ss.getRange(6, 1, ss.getLastRow() - STOCKDATA_ROW_OFFSET, ss.getLastColumn()).moveTo(ss.getRange(7, 1));
}}


function pdfToDoc() {
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById('16wk3cb81Qj31o9Z8rvmpQ19_yM-K2QxxIc').getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true,
    convert: true
  };
  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
  Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);
}
```

---

I found a [tutorial](https://yagisanatode.com/2020/04/17/google-apps-script-get-google-doc-text-based-on-reference-characters/), unfortunately it doesn't work and I get an error message.

```
//Search for DATA
function searchData(){
  const docID = "13TlciLOZV-rxj31aV4qFd3d3eBoMuEocGNg3CSb7_uXXoZDQ";
  const identifier = {
    start: ``,
    start_include: false,
    end: ``,
    end_include: false
  };
  let results = getDocItems(docID, identifier);
  console.log(results);
};
```

The following error message comes up.
**ReferenceError: getDocItems is not defined (...)**

Comment: I think that in your situation, how about the following flow? 1. Convert PDF data to Google Document. 2. Retrieve the values you want. 3. Put the values to the Spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot check your actual PDF file. So I cannot directly suggest the modified script. So here, I suggested the possible flow for achieving your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and report.

Comment: @Tanaike i am making progress but need a little support. maybe you can think of something, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But as I have already mentioned my previous comment, unfortunately, I cannot check your actual PDF file. So I cannot directly suggest the modified script. So here, I suggested the possible flow for achieving your goal. I apologize for this. But from `ReferenceError: getDocItems is not defined`, it seems that `getDocItems` is not defined. But I cannot image your whole script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So how about confirming it again?